# When I click the button, opening of new forms and writing something

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a code like that,

```
#-*- coding: cp857 -*-

from tkinter import *

###########################################################

root=Tk()

root.title("MY FILMS v1")

root.resizable(False, False)

###########################################################


def about():
    about=Tk()
    about.title("About!")
    about.resizable(False,False)
    label1=Label(text="Creator name is Emek :)")
    label1.pack()
    mainloop()



button=Button(text="About",command=about, font=("Flux",15, "bold"))
button.pack(expand="yes", anchor="center")

mainloop()
```

I want to when I click the button, opening a new forms and writing something but opening a new form but title stay in root :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify what window to place the label in.  This can be done by passing the window's handle as the first argument of the label:

```
label1=Label(about, text="Creator name is Emek :)")
```

If you do not explicitly give them a window handle, Tkinter widgets will be placed in whatever window was open first.

Comment: I understand.I'm new at Tkinter :)